# Retrieve columns from a csv files and extract value to another csv file

Tags: python, csv

I have a csv file as follow:

```
lat,lon,date,data1,data2
1,2,3,4,5
6,7,8,9,10
```

From this csv file I want to retrieve and extract the column date and data1 to another csv file. I have the following code:

```
import csv
os.chdir(mydir)
column_names = ["date", "data1"]
index=[]
with open("my.csv", "r") as f:
mycsv = csv.DictReader(f)
for row in mycsv:
    for col in column_names:
        try:
            data=print(row[col])
            with open("test2.txt", "w") as f:
                print(data, file=f)
        except KeyError:
            pass
```

Unfortunately, the output is a file with a "none" on it... Does anyone knows how to retrieve and write to another file the data I wish to use?

Comment: use csv.writer or [DictWriter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.DictWriter) from [CSV module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html)

Comment: @akshat yes it's exactly what my code does. The problem is the output is different from what I expected!

Comment: you are not using `DictWriter` or `writer` from `CSV` module. See my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why you see `None` in your file is because you're assigning the result of `print(row[col])` to your `data` variable:

```
data=print(row[col])
```

`print()` doesn't return anything, therefore the content of `data` is `None`. If you remove the `print()` and just have `data = row[col]`, you will get something valuable.

There is one more issue that I see in your code, which you probably want to get fixed:

You're opening the file over and over again with each iteration in the first loop. Therefore, with each row you're overwriting the entire file with that rows value. If you want the entire column, then you'd have open the file once, before the loop.

Comment: Another suggestion that I have - which are not directly related to your question though - is to use `f.write()` instead of `print(data, file=f)`. `f.write()` is more explicit and understandable at first than redirecting print to a file-like object.

Answer (score 3):

There are a few issues with your code:

1. Everytime you `open("test2.txt", "w")`, `w` option will open your file and delete all its contents.
2. You are storing `return` value or `print`, which is `None` and then trying to `print` this into yout file

Read your CSV into a `list` of `dict`'s, as below:

```
import csv
with open('your_csv.csv') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)

    read_l = [{key:value for key, value in row.items() if key in ('date', 'data1')}
              for row in reader]
```

and then use `DictWriter` to write to a new CSV.

```
with open('new.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
    fieldnames = read_l[0].keys()
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)
    writer.writeheader()
    for row in read_l[1:]:
        writer.writerow(row)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try with below steps may help you. But they require pandas library.Install pandas library before you go for below steps. input.csv contains data that you have mentioned.

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_csv('input.csv')
df_new=df.iloc[0:,2:4]
df_new.to_csv("output.csv",index=False)
```

Answer (score 1):

I will recommend you should use panda. I haven't run this script but something like this should work.

```
import panda as pd
import csv

frame = pd.read_csv('my.csv')
df=frame[['date','data2']]
with open('test2.csv', 'a', newline='') as csvfile:
        writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',',
                            quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL) 



        writer.writerow(df)
```

Comment: While I agree that pandas is a great framework, I think it might be a bit overkill to load it for this particular purpose. The task in question is very simple and minimalistic, and can be easily done within the standard library with a similar amount of work.

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("my.csv") #optional "header"=True

new_df = df[["date","data1"]]

new_df.to_csv("new_csv_name.csv")

#if you don't need index
new_df.to_csv('new_csv_name.csv', index=False)
```